# php- Exec() How to parse xml file in background?

Tags: php, simplexml, exec

I am facing a problem while generating xml file in background
My execute function is

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("cmd C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php-win.exe -f C:/wamp/www/Test-Xml/test_insert.php", 0, false);
```

But I am unable to generate xml while the command is working without any error.
My generate xml is working fine but when I use the execute command it doesn't work.

Comment: Why? Why on earth would you parse XML as a pseudo child process? what's the point? What errors are you getting? what version, what plugins?

Comment: I want to generate xml and sync the xml file received from a remote server (which is facing a connectivity issue) into our main server database. I am currently using php 5.3.13 and simplexml_load_file to generate xml.